# Unpacking data from Hexadecimal to float

Tags: c, floating-point, hex, endianness

I've got incoming data in Big Endian format

```
uint8_t u8DataA[] = {0x40, 0xAD, 0x70, 0xB8};
```

which needs to get unpacked to *float*. The result should be **3768.36**. No mater how I stuff bytes into float I don't get this result. How do I do this?

Comment: According to [IEEE 754 calculator](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/), `3768.36` should be `{0x45, 0x6B, 0x85, 0xC3}`. Stuffing these in a union [gives the desired result](http://ideone.com/zCgBNt).

Comment: "The result should be .." Are you **sure** of that? If this is an IEEE 754 floating point number, I get either -0.000057 or 5.420010 with the usual conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the first four bytes of a 64-bit `double` representation, not the four bytes of a 32-byte representation.

According to the IEEE 754 calculator, 64-bit representation of `3768.36` is

```
0x40, 0xAD, 0x70, 0xB8, 0x51, 0xEB, 0x85, 0x1F
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
This is what you have   This part is missing
```

You took the first four bytes of it, and tried re-interpreting it as a `float`. That's why it did not work.

A 32-bit representation of `3768.36` is

```
0x45, 0x6B, 0x85, 0xC3
```

Converting it to `float` by stuffing the bytes into an array and re-interpreting produces the desired result ([demo](http://ideone.com/zCgBNt)).

Comment: It was an error in the documentation of the device I am working with. Imagine that!

Comment: @Primož'c0dehunter'Kralj Knowing how the technical documentation is produced, I am not overly surprised :-)

Answer (score 0):

Passing these hexadecimal number to decimal directly would be useless. If you know how to convert a decimal number to float, just try to convert these hex numbers to binary, and once you have an entire binary number (for example: 0000 1111 0010 1101 1111 1110 0001 0010. Having it as a string would help, but I don't know which functions nor how many functions allow you to work with binary numbers) you would only have to extract the exponent, sign and mantissa. If you don't know how to convert integers to float, have a look through the internet and choose the best tutorial for you. Keep in mind that, once you have the binary number as a string, taking the sign, mantissa and exponent is not much difficult. If you have some kind of function which converts binary to decimal, you can deal with that easily.